# JMeter - Loop Count time taken

Tags: multithreading, loops, time, count, jmeter

#Thread: 20, Ramp-up: 10s, Loop Count: 1000

20 Thread will up and running 10 seconds (2 Thread = 1 Second interval).
So once the 20 thread completes, next loop starts again 20 thread starts up within 10seconds interval ?
And next loopx1, 20 open within 10 seconds again, closes
And next loopx2, 20 open within 10 seconds again, closes...
..And next loopx1000, 20 open within 10 seconds.

So 1000 loop, 10seconds x 1000 = 10,000 seconds /60 = 167 minutes JMeter will complete
But my program completes 13minutes.

I guess the 20threads, some finishes early so does this mean in loop 1 maybe 7 threads still running, but we already moved into loop 2 to start the finished threads ? Is that why it finished earlier ?

Answer (score 1):

Following is an extract from the Apache JMeter official website.

[Ramup-up period](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html)

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.

In your scenario with 20 threads and 10 seconds ramp-up period

| Time | Number of threads |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 5 | 12 |
| 6 | 14 |
| 7 | 16 |
| 8 | 18 |
| 9 | 20 |

Actually, **after 9 seconds all 20 threads** will be up and running.

[Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) documentation
[image]

You can set up a sample test plan and see how threads are getting ramped up in the right top JMeter IDE
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, no, no and no.

Thread: 20, Ramp-up: 10s, Loop Count: 1000 means that:

- JMeter will start 20 threads in 10 seconds, i.e. 2 threads per second, after 10 seconds all 20 threads will be up and running
- Once started each thread will start executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))
- When there are no more Samplers to execute the thread starts the next iteration, it will not wait for the other Threads unless you explicitly tell it using i.e. [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)
- When there are no more loops to iterate the thread is being shut down
- When the last thread executes the last Sampler in the last iteration the test ends

The total test duration depends on response time of your Sampler(s) and you cannot precisely calculate it beforehand